# WebView not prompting for intranet login

Tags: c#, wpf, webview

I have a sample WPF application which uses tabs to allow a user to navigate to a uri with different embedded browsers. I've added Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls to my project and am attempting to use a WebView for one of the tabs.

Using

```
<WebBrowser Name="Browser" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

I get a security challenge when accessing our company's intranet site. This is good!

Using

```
<Window x:Class="BrowserTester.MainWindow"
    xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls"
...
>
...
  <WPF:WebView Name="WebView" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

I do not get a security challenge when accessing our company's intranet site. I simply get the failed logon page. This is bad!

Using Edge I get prompted, so WebView should, in theory, work with the correct settings:

[image: Windows Security Prompt]

I've also set:

```
WebView.Settings.IsScriptNotifyAllowed = true;
```

to no avail.

I've added the site explicitly to Internet Options' `Local Intranet` Zone, per the recommendation of one site for Windows Integrated Authentication and set the `User Authentication` > `Logon` to "Prompt for user name and password".

The documentation for WebView doesn't deal with authentication, so I'm somewhat stumped in my research.

When examining the network traffic in Edge, I see the following:

```
Status Code: 401 / Unauthorized
```

In the response headers I see:

```
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=***.*****.com
```

which may provide clues as to what is going on.

Comment: The question is how the web page with login script is implemented. WebView is based if I'm not mistaken on IE and not on the newest version. See remarks to [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView)

Comment: WebBrowser is based on IE and works just fine. The WebView you're looking at isn't the one I'm using. From the link you provided: "In apps compiled for Windows 10, WebView uses the Microsoft Edge rendering engine to display HTML content."

Comment: Seems as though I need to handle WWW-Authenticate with an Authorization request using the correct type and credentials. Will see how this works out.

Comment: Did you solve this?